# Does “every element of a set $A$ is $m^*$-measurable” imply that “every element of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$ is $m^*$-measurable”?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A$ is a subset of the ground set $X$ such that every element in $A$ is $m^*$-measurable.
Then, can I say that every element of the $\sigma$-algebra $B$, generated by $A$, is $m^*$-measurable?
Here, by “a set $A$ is $m^*$-measurable” I mean that, for all $E$ in $X$,
$m^*(E) = m^*(E \cap A) + m^*(E - A)$.

Comment: I think no. The elements of $A$ are singletons $A= \bigcup_{x \in A} \{x\}$, so while they may be $m$*-measurable, I don't think this is enough to imply that other unions are $m$*-measurable. Could be true depending on what $m$* is, but I believe we indeed need further information. I'm guessing no because what if the set itself isn't measurable? I mean I guess it's possible that there's some measure $\mu$ and non-$\mu$-measurable set A s.t. $\forall a \in A, \{a\}$ is $\mu$-measurable. Maybe it applies to $\mu=m$*. After all, $\{a\}$ is just a singleton.